# Trouble with textboxes losing focus in Visual Basic .net

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2013, textbox

Recently I got an assignment to make a very basic Sudoku-game in Visual Basic.
To make this I am using Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 Update 4 with the .NET Framework.

I have gotten to the point where I can check which one out of many textboxes has focus. With this also change the backgroundColor of the corresponding textbox.
I have done this using this by using this method:

`Private Sub TextBox_GotFocus() Handles TextBox1.GotFocus, TextBox2.GotFocus, TextBox3.GotFocus
     Me.ActiveControl.BackColor = Color.Aquamarine
End Sub`

To Color it back to white when any of the textboxes lost focus I used this:

`Private Sub TextBox_LostFocus() Handles TextBox1.LostFocus, TextBox2.LostFocus, TextBox3.LostFocus
     Me.ActiveControl.BackColor = Color.White
End Sub`

**Now My Questions Are:**

1. Why does the Application crash when I close it? And how do I fix this?

(It Gives a NullReferenceException when being closed)

2. Is this even a proper way to accomplish what I want? Or is there something more efficient?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add object, EventArgs as parameters.

;

The object will be the calling control which invokes the event.

```
Private Sub TextBox_GotFocus(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.GotFocus, TextBox2.GotFocus, TextBox3.GotFocus
    CType(sender, TextBox).BackColor = Color.Aquamarine
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox_LostFocus(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.LostFocus, TextBox2.LostFocus, TextBox3.LostFocus
    CType(sender, TextBox).BackColor = Color.White
End Sub
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank You Very Much! And Thanks For The Easy And Clear Explanation :D

Comment: I Now Added It as an answer, and as a 'new' member i can't upvote yet sadly.